# SUBSTRING_INDEX query with double quotes does not work in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to fetch data from database which contain data in serialize format.

Below MySQL query is running in SQL and returns data properly.

```
SELECT * FROM `wpyr_ads` 
WHERE 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`column`, '"age";s:2:"', -1), '"', 1) BETWEEN 25 AND 30
```

But using PHP its not working due to quotes.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `wpyr_ads` WHERE 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`column`, '"age";s:2:"', -1), '"', 1) BETWEEN 25 AND 30"
```

Please let me know how can I do this.

Comment: You should escape the double quotes: `$query = "SELECT * FROM wpyr_ads WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, '\"age\";s:2:\"', -1), '\"', 1) BETWEEN 25 AND 30"`

Comment: Thanks, its working!!

Answer (score 0):

You have this issue since you use double quotes to create a string literal in PHP:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `wpyr_ads` WHERE ... "
//       ^                                   ^ these double quotes
```

When you include more double quotes inside this literal, each one of them ends the previous string literal, which is not what you want. To tell PHP that these quotes are not a part a syntax construction, but a part of a string, you need to escape them:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `wpyr_ads` WHERE 
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`column`, '\"age\";s:2:\"', -1), '\"', 1) BETWEEN 25 AND 30"
```

Read [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) for more info about double quoted strings in PHP.